# How to test multiple files in Zig?

Tags: testing, zig

In main.zig I am importing some file lexer.zig that contains some tests

```
const lxr = @import("lexer");

some code

test {
    std.testing.refAllDecls(@This());
}
```

However when running `zig build test`, the tests in lexer.zig are ignored.

Here are the relevant lines of the `build.zig` file

```
const exe = b.addExecutable("main", "src/main.zig");
exe.addPackagePath("lexer", "src/lexer.zig");

const exe_tests = b.addTest("src/main.zig");
exe_tests.addPackagePath("lexer", "src/lexer.zig");

const test_step = b.step("test", "Run unit tests");
test_step.dependOn(&exe_tests.step);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Import `lexer.zig` as a normal Zig file, instead of adding it as a package.
2. Something from `lexer.zig` must be used in the same file where `refAllDecl` appears, or Zig won't include the file and tests won't be included either.

A common way to do tests is to add `tests.zig` with contents like

```
comptime {
    _ = @import("lexer.zig");
    // And all other files
}
```

And in `build.zig`: `b.addTest("src/main.zig")` is replaced by `b.addTest("src/tests.zig")`.

Comment: Great, thank you, what is the reason to use comptime here?

Comment: @John It forces Zig to import the files. You could try dropping the `comptime`, you'll find that the tests get excluded again.

Comment: I have one last question if you don't mind, when to import as a package and when to import as a file? Thanks

Comment: Packages are for third-party libraries. Unless you're making part of the project into an independent library, you should always import as a file.

Answer (score 1):

I found that unless the import is marked `pub` it will not be tested. I have a standard build.zig file as generated by `zig init-exe` as of version 0.11.

This will test all tests for the imports marked pub. I am not sure if this is a good practice though, especially for an executable or library with private interfaces. Here is a simple example:

main.zig

```
pub const lxr = @import("lexer.zig");

pub fn main() void {}

test {
    std.testing.refAllDecls(@This());
}
```

lexer.zig

```
const std = @import("std");

test "lexer test" {
    try std.testing.expect(0 == 1);
}
```